# Mistake when use abaqus subroutine to read file with multiple processors(cpus)

Tags: subroutine, multiprocessor, abaqus

I got a mistake when I use abaqus subroutine to read file with multiple processors(cpus),could you help me to deal with this mistake.thanks a lot

I want to read variables from a file ,when one cpu is used,everything is ok,
but when more than one cpus are used,there will be a mistake,it seems that every cpu repeat the same command.

for example,the following is the contents of the file to read from,file name is data.dat

*matID      ,2,1

131000.000,    8880.000,    8180.000

```
   0.324,       0.324,       0.300

3990.000,    5320.000,    5320.000

1871.000,      59.700,      59.700

1291.000,     215.000,     215.000

  90.000,     102.000,     102.000
```

my subroutine is shown as follow:
      character*12  check1
      integer check2,error
      OPEN(10,file='data.dat',status='old',iostat=error)
      if (error.EQ.0) then
          read(10,*,iostat=error) check1,Nm 
      end if
      close(10)
      print *,'Nm=',nm,error
      print *,'**'

when I use 2 cpus,the printed results will be :

Nm=           2           0

Nm=        8880           0

**

**

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the reason for reading in data from a file, there are a couple of ways to avoid this problem:

**If you only need to access the data once**:
Read in the data in a subroutine that is always called in serial. UEXTERNALDB is a good example and can be used so that the file open only happens at the beginning of an analysis or the beginning of an increment as needed. You can then carefully store the information in common blocks. Reading from a common block in parallel should work fine, but do not write to them from the parallel subroutines.

Another way to get in a smaller amount of data is to define solution variables in your input file instead.

**If you really need to open this file locally within each parallel thread** (can't see why but open to correction), you can use GETNUMCPUS and GETRANK to open different copies of the files within each thread. GETRANK returns an integer giving you the rank/id of the process. I would advise against this method though. If your problem is large enough to warrant using parallel, then you should avoid slowing it down with file reads.

For more info see sections 1.1.31 and 2.1.4 of the Abaqus 6.14 docs.